Is it possible to create a command alias that is usable through SSH?
Let's say I have an alias like ll='ls -l' but I also want to be able to use it on any server I access using SSH, no matter what OS or user (provided ls -l actually works of course).
Is this possible? I'm open to using a different terminal application as well if that is needed.

You could create a small script, which always tries to copy your local alias file to the remote machine and making sure that the remote alias file is called. After it's done, it would then connect to the machine.

@paladin The issue with that would be that if I log in to a user that other people use too, it could lead to issues

-t option could be used to specify commands that are executed on server side. See this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1236475/62676

@Robert Can I use this to create an alias for that specific session then?

I haven't tried it but to me it seems like it should be possible.

Hosts of arbitrary operating system, possibly unmanaged, are not guaranteed to be set up in the way you expect. Including shell configuration, of course.
Write your scripts in a portable and self contained way. If you require aliases and functions, source the separate file yourself, do not assume a login shell. Use programs designed to be scripted, like find  to list files.  Possibly use a scripting language other than shell, Ansible automation framework makes use of Python for example.
For interactive use, automate the install of the configuration such that its on all relevant servers. Some distros have shell profiles that sources drop in files in /etc/profile.d/  make use of this to install a custom file for all users. Or, there also are user specific shell files, if this is a personal convenience that does not need to be shared. Everyone with a login shell should have a personal user anyway, for an audit trail to trace activity to a person.
